# What is the risk of permanent brain damage and/or long term cognitive effects from a single exposure to extreme altitude?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, cognition

I have read some of the papers on the subject of the permanent brain damage induced by high to extreme altitude (5000m-8000m) climbing. The evidence seems contradictory. One paper (Fayed 2006) found significant post expedition MRI findings including white matter hyperintensities but this finding seemingly is in doubt for lower altitudes where studies other than this one have only picked up more temporary changes (usually in white matter fraction). The evidence for 8000m+ climbs seems clearer, in that it is clearly more damaging.

I would consequently be interested in any views based on the available evidence of the risk of permanent damage of a single 'normal' sojourn to 5000m to 7000m if acclimatisation profile is reasonable and HAPE / HACE do not obviously manifest.

The brain is evidently highly sensitive to hypoxia and there is some well evidenced impact on cognition whilst at high altitudes but do mountaineers exposed to these sub 8000m altitudes risk longer term damage?

Some relevant papers:

Fayed et al 2006 paper that was extensively picked up in the media but did not do pre expedition MRI: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Evidence-of-brain-damage-after-high-altitude-by-of-Fayed-Modrego/f182e5c8a73b505e66e50bcb671ee8cf86c0f6f5

Fan et al paper on reversible abnormalities https://www.nature.com/articles/srep33596

Kotke et al paper finding limited evidence of structural damage (Morphological Brain Changes after Climbing to Extreme Altitudes--A Prospective Cohort Study) https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0141097

Dr Peter Hackett study on Denali - https://www.boulderweekly.com/adventure/this-is-your-brain-this-is-your-brain-at-altitude/

Comment: Your references aren't contradictory. The papers you cited (and others) all show the risk of permanent brain injury is obvious. (The Nature article showed persistent changes.)The pre-/post-HA MRIs study supports the Nature study. Brain changes at lower altitudes were observed in the late 1890's and in Fayed's later papers. The answer is most likely ["high"](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/brain-cells-into-thin-air/)). But does this brain damage manifest in permanently diminished post-climb capacities? That would be my question.

Comment: I do think the evidence is unclear e.g. Kottke et al (up to 7000m). No white matter hyperintensities nor grey matter atrophy but a decrease in brain WM fraction. Foster et al 2015 (3 weeks at 5000m) observed a GM reduction, while WM was unchanged. 
Zhang et al (6200m): "disturbances mainly in cerebral WM, showing compromised fiber microstructural integrity".

Hackett study detailed here (https://www.boulderweekly.com/adventure/this-is-your-brain-this-is-your-brain-at-altitude/) found increased WM volume and subcortical climbers in 6% of climbers of Denali (6300m); the rest normal on MRI

Comment: So one paper found a decrease in grey matter but no decrease in white matter. Other papers found a decrease in white matter but no decrease in grey matter. Some papers found largely normal MRIs except when obvious severe AMS developed. Some papers found certain cognitive functions (e.g. motor or memory) had been affected, others found nothing. Is neuroscience always like this?!

Comment: @Anothercanary Yes, science with small samples is always like this. Those results need not be contradictory as they seem.

Comment: From my limited reading of the literature, it seems fairly clear - even with the small sample sizes - that permanent brain *changes* (call it damage if you will) do occur at lower altitudes, especially in novices. Do they occur in everyone in the same way? No. Do they matter? You'd need longitudinal studies (neuropsychiatric evaluations at intervals for years) to answer that. The longer the study, the more confounding issues result, muddying the conclusions. @BryanKrause, you're a neuroscientist, no? am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It's a shame there is no definitive view as it makes individual decision making about HA trips difficult as you're missing one side of the risk-reward equation. This study hypothesises: "There may be various reasons for these inconsistencies: different high-altitude experiences of climbers, manifestation of neurological disturbances during or after the expedition, [or] the use of different MRI techniques." https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1468-1331.2008.02243.x